# How do I make my code run in a for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wanted to make this kinda code run in for loop rather me putting 3,6,9 and so on and similarly for total cars i.e 2,3,4.
Because what I'm doing does not seem to be a good approach.

Code:

```
 data[(( data.total_people > 3 )& (data.total_cars < 2 )) | (( data.total_people > 6 )& (data.total_cars < 3 )) ]
```

Data:

```
 total_people   total_cars
2   4.0         1
7   5.0         1
19  4.0         1
21  6.0         1
40  4.0         1
43  4.0         1
48  4.0         1
```

Data is about people are more than 3 and car is only one.
people are more than 6 and car is only 2 and so on for 9,12.
I thought about adding 3 to total people like 3,6,9,12 and 1 each time to cars but how i'll do this in for loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: If you are looking for the ratio of people to cars, try dividing the number of people by the number of cars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should clarify a bit. Is this what you had in mind?

```
for i in range(0, n):
    data[(( data.total_people > 3*(i+1) )& (data.total_cars == i+1 ))]    
    #process your data here
```

Where n is how many times you want to check

n = 1 => 3 people, 1 car

n = 2 => 6 people, 2 cars

n = 3 => 9 people, 3 cars
etc

Comment: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: I'm kinda new to this stuff. SO

Comment: When i give some val in place of n. len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: That is almost certainly not what they want to do. You're filtering a whole dataframe in a loop now, which doesn't make any sense

Comment: you could either declare n = 5 or whatever value you want before, or just replace the n with the number you want

Comment: @PopescuDavidIoan len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @igneas its not len(0,n), its range(0, n). I edited the answer just after I posted it, i dont know why you didn't see the edited version.

Comment: @PopescuDavidIoan It does not give the desired output. Only the N=6 gets displayed

Comment: That is only the structure of a loop, as your question says. That is how to write a loop for the condtions described. You did not say what your code should do, the question is ambiguous so I gave you the structure of the for loop and left you to implement whatever logic you want inside the body of the for

Comment: Yeah. Got it. hmm